# In PHP GD how would I determine if a pixel is a shade of red?

Tags: php, gd

I want to create a sort of "Grayscale everything except for red" effect. To do this I have this code

```
<?php
    header('content-type: image/png');
    $image = imagecreatefrompng('a.png');
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

From here I plan on looping through the original a.png pixels and set any shades of red back on it after filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to tell if a pixel is red? You can use [`imagecolorat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php):

```
$col = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
```

Which is the color in RGB so '($col >> 16) & 0xFF' is the red component. Now you can't just check the red component because other components might change it to more purple or orange and it depends how far down you want to go, but something like this will be true if there's more red than green or blue:

```
$r = ($col >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($col >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $col & 0xFF;

$limit = 2; // Aim for 2 times more red 

$is_red = ($r / $limit) > ($g + $b);
```

You can play with `$limit` or try different logic.

There may already be a GD filter that does this, but I'm not familiar with the filters.

**EDIT**

This looked like something that might come in useful in the future, so I knocked up a little function to do it:

```
function colorInGreyFilter($im, $limit = 1.5, $rgb_choice = 0) { 

  $sx = imagesx($im); 
  $sy = imagesy($im); 

  for ($x = 0; $x < $sx; $x++ ) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $sy; $y++ ) {

      // Get the color and split the RGB values into an array 
      $col = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
      $rgb = array( ($col >> 16) & 0xFF, ($col >> 8) & 0xFF, $col & 0xFF );

      // Get the rgb value we're intested in;
      $trg_col = $rgb[$rgb_choice]; 

      // If the value of the target color is more than $limit times
      // the sum of the other colors then we use that pixel so 
      // we only greyscale the pixel if it's less ...
      if (($trg_col / $limit) < (array_sum($rgb) - $trg_col)) {

        // Use the average of the values as the setting 
        // for the grey scale RGB values
        $avg = (array_sum($rgb) / 3) & 0xFF;;
        $col = ($avg <<16) + ($avg << 8) + $avg;
        imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $col);

      }
      /* 
       else { 
         Could have the option of taking a target image that's already 
     filtered, so here we would copy the pixel to the target 
       }
      */
    }
  }
}
```

This takes an image and applies the greyscale algorithm to everything but the pixels that match the criteria. You can change the limit and choose to use red, green or blue as the main colour:

```
colorInGreyFilter($im);        // Greyscale with red highlights (the default)
colorInGreyFilter($im, .5, 1); // Greyscale with lots of green left
colorInGreyFilter($im,  2, 2); // Greyscale with only the bluest blue left
```

It does greys with a simple average of the RGB values -- which is OK but not as refined as the GD filter -- so a good expansion would be to optionally allow a pre-filtered target image.

Comment: So $limit would be a threshold of the shade of red? I don't want JUST red, i want shades too.

Comment: Yes -- anything where $r > 0 and $b == $g == 0 is basically a shade of red. But other things with just a little green and blue are arguable 'shades of red' too. So a simple test is 'is there twice as much red as there is blue and green?'. But if you adjust limit it'll change the 'twice as much' part. If you look here: http://www.colorpicker.com/ you can play with the colors to see the Red, Green, Blue values and see what's true for what you consider red. But if you're going for the common red on grayscale approach I think that limit would be fine.

Comment: @Ugleh You would have to convert the RGB values to something like HSV first.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax

```
int imagecolorat ( resource $image , int $x , int $y )
```

Returns the index of the color of the pixel at the specified location in the image specified by image

If PHP is compiled against GD library 2.0 or higher and the image is a truecolor image, this function returns the RGB value of that pixel as integer. Use bitshifting and masking to access the distinct red, green and blue component values

Example:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("php.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;

var_dump($r, $g, $b);
?>
```